# Is there a utility that allows to create structured data from tcpdump hexdumps?

Tags: linux, networking, tcpdump, wireshark, hexdump

Sometimes I have to use `tcpdump` to troubleshoot problems with networking protocols that `tcpdump` does not know how to parse.

**Is there a utility that could read tcpdump packets in hex dump format and then parse them according to structure I specified for this utility?**

Something like:

```
tcpdump -nxi any udp | the_utility "Packet_id:%d@60"
```

for each packet would print:

```
Packet_id:1
Packet_id:2
Packet_id:4
Packet_id:3
```

The idea is that at offset 60 there is 32 bit integer that I want to be printed in decimal format to STDOUT.

*I understand that IP fragmentation and TCP reassembly would require to pass along some state to the next hex dump for it to be properly interpreted. Let's assume this is not a problem for me. Nevertheless if you know of an elegant solution that could solve this, then that would be great.*

*While I like Wireshark, I don't always have an option to copy packet capture files to my workstation for offline inspection. Also, these are production appliances where I have to run tcpdump - this means that I need a solution where I would not have to install anything extra.*

Comment: Wireshark is available on some Linux distros (or more exactly repositories), at least CentOS (I presume other RedHat also) and Debian. If the interactive/GUI features aren't wanted, it includes a commandline form `tshark`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Unfortunately, I can't install wireshark, because the hosts don't have graphical interface, they sometimes don't even belong to me and sometime they are appliances where yum and apt-get is not connected to official Linux distros.

Comment: So, if there were such a utility, you could install it on the machines in question, but you couldn't install Wireshark on the machines in question - not even the non-GUI parts of Wireshark (most of the code isn't GUI code, and there's tshark, which is a command-line packet capture and analysis program using the same dissectors that Wireshark uses)?

Comment: @GuyHarris To be more specific - the appliances where I want to run tcpdump are based on standard ubuntu, but with stripped /etc/apt/sources.list file. I was hoping that such "utility" would exist on standard Ubuntu distribution already pre-installed and I would not have to install anything extra. For example there is hd, xdd and similar utilities, but they don't work quite well when piping from tcpdump.

Comment: Is `perl` or `python` an option?  `perl` has a `Net::Pcap` module which can be used to write custom packet-capture scripts, and `python` has the `pcapy` library.   And there's always `C` and the `pcap` library.   and even without those libraries, you can pipe `tcpdump -x`'s output into `perl` or `awk` or even `python` and process it there to get the output you want.  depending on exactly what you want to do you could probably hack something up with just `tcpdump`, `grep`, and `sed`.  i.e. there is no tool to do exactly what you want, you'll have to write something yourself.

Comment: btw, even without a default `sources.list` file you can manually download packages such as the CLI utility `tshark` (e.g. with `curl` or `wget`) and all their dependencies and install them with `dpkg`.  Be careful of conflicts with other installed packages.